# Have multiple Urls for viewing logs in spinnaker

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker

I want to have different urls for different accounts for viewing pod logs

I was thinking to pass a variable but the problem is how to get the account variable in deck configuration ?

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] of your tries. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You could expand your question with more details. Basically you could get the current Account and metadata with [Pipeline Expressions](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/).

To [create custom Links](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/instance-links/) you can combine the data available in your pipeline if you check the JSON source of the pipeline and identify the objects and attributes required. Also remember you can use Pipeline Expressions to extract values for your custom links as well.